# Reshape long format data to one line wide format data

Tags: r, reshape2, tidyr

I'm trying to reshape some data from a long format to a single line wide format, below is how my data currently looks;

```
id var1 var2 var3
1     a    b    c
2     d    e    f
3     g    h    i
```

Below is how I'd like my data to look at the end;

```
id.1 var1.1 var2.1 var3.1 id.2 var1.2 var2.2 var3.2 id.3 var1.3 var2.3 var3.3
1         a      b      c    2      d      e      f    3      g      h      i
```

I've tried using the `tidyr` package and `reshape` but neither seem to be capable of what I want to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think just `unlist(df)` does what you want (assuming you have no factors there and you don't care about the order). Or `c(t(df))` will give the values in desired order but without the names.

Comment: Or, I suppose `do.call(cbind, split(mydf, 1:nrow(mydf)))`,  but *why*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If maintaining column types is of interest, you can try `do.call(cbind, split(mydf, 1:nrow(mydf)))`.

Example:

```
mydf <- structure(list(id = 1:3, var1 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("a",      
         "d", "g"), class = "factor"), var2 = c("b", "e", "h"), var3 = c("c",    
         "f", "i")), .Names = c("id", "var1", "var2", "var3"), row.names = c(NA, 
         3L), class = "data.frame")
```

^^ This is like your data, but the "var1" column is a factor.

```
do.call(cbind, split(mydf, 1:nrow(mydf)))
#   1.id 1.var1 1.var2 1.var3 2.id 2.var1 2.var2 2.var3 3.id 3.var1 3.var2 3.var3
# 1    1      a      b      c    2      d      e      f    3      g      h      i

str(.Last.value)
# 'data.frame': 1 obs. of  12 variables:
#  $ 1.id  : int 1
#  $ 1.var1: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","d","g": 1
#  $ 1.var2: chr "b"
#  $ 1.var3: chr "c"
#  $ 2.id  : int 2
#  $ 2.var1: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","d","g": 2
#  $ 2.var2: chr "e"
#  $ 2.var3: chr "f"
#  $ 3.id  : int 3
#  $ 3.var1: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","d","g": 3
#  $ 3.var2: chr "h"
#  $ 3.var3: chr "i"
```

^^ Note that column classes are retained.

A little `gsub` can get the column names to be what you were expecting.

---

Or, you can add two additional columns, one filled with the value "1", the other with the sequence from 1 to the number of rows in your dataset, and use that as your "id" (LHS) and "time" (RHS) variables with the `reshape` function, or something like the `data.table` version of `dcast` that accepts multiple variables for `value.var`.

Answer (score 0):

The `reshape2` package. Example: http://seananderson.ca/2013/10/19/reshape.html

Comment: Isn't it a comment?